# How to do HTTP post many form fields in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am making forms with lots of fields in Vuejs and then I have to make an HTTP post in these forms to the APIs that process the field changes.

Naturally I am using data binding to validate and process some of the form fields, but at the end, I want to http post all the form fields at once.

The best thing I found so far was to directly access the HTML element of the submit event. This is what I am currently doing:

```
<form @submit.prevent="submit($event)">
...
</form>
```

```
async function submit(event) {
    // ... validate/preprocess databound form fields
    const data = new FormData(event.srcElement)
    const res = await fetch("saveChanges.php", {
        method: 'post',
        body: data,
    })
    jsonResponse = await res.json()
    // ... process jsonResponse fields
}
```

Comment: Instead of accessing the DOM directly you could bind the form inputs to reactive data variables, then append those values to `FormData` object.  This also makes it easier to perform other actions like validate or clear the values as needed.

Comment: As I explained in the question, I am already using data binding. my issue is that I have big forms with many many fields and I want to send an HTTP post will all these form fields, after I validate them.

Comment: You just need to [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) the different binded values to your `data` FormData object.  They will all be POSTed together.

Comment: yeah, but I don't want to manually append dozens of fields there. I was looking for a solution that could access all the form fields at once. new FormData(event.srcElement) worked nicely for me, but I was wondering if vuejs had something else that yielded a similar result

Comment: Sorry I don't know how your data is structured.  I was thinking if all your fields were inside of an array or object you could just append them all with a for loop.

Comment: `const data = new FormData(event.srcElement)` is an oneliner. it seems easier than a for loop...

Comment: The FormData constructor can only be given a HTML DOM element, so the alternative options are rather limited.  If a 1 line solution is the requirement then that's what you should go with.